# Any way to make git-lfs not download objects for files not in repo?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a git-lfs object that was deleted from our git repo a year ago.  When we clone, it still downloads the LFS object in case someone ever needs to go back to that revision in history.  Problem is: the file is an executable and is triggering Windows defender on clone operations.  If we set the environment to skip smudge and then do a git lfs pull then the problem goes away, but it seems wasteful to download LFS objects that are very unlikely to ever be needed.

Is there any way to either:

a) Delete the object from the LFS server and have git clone still succeed but just ignore the file?

b) Tell git not to download lfs objects either for specific commit hashes, objects, dates, file names, or some other way of excluding certain objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Git LFS only downloads files as they are needed for checking out a repository.  That's the case because Git passes the pointer files to Git LFS, which then makes a list of objects to download and downloads them.  Git LFS doesn't normally prefetch files for other revisions unless you ask it to.

If Git LFS is downloading this object and you're not explicitly asking it to with `git lfs fetch` or `git lfs pull`, then it's probably still referenced somewhere in your working tree.

Note that if you delete the file, that will cause an error when checking out that revision, so you don't want to do that.  You can use the `lfs.fetchexclude` configuration option, which is mentioned in the documentation, to exclude certain files, but it will probably be easier to just find where the file is referenced and make sure it's gone.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Does this mean that there are cases where you clone a repo, then `git checkout <some-really-old-revision>` while offline, and the LFS objects aren't available locally because they weren't pre-fetched, so you have to connect to internet and `git lfs pull` before the build works?  I was under the impression it downloaded all history locally so that you could work offline at an arbitrary revision.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Unlike Git, Git LFS doesn't by default download objects that aren't needed to check out a current revision.  That's because part of the goal is to improve disk usage, and downloading all objects from the entire history wouldn't really improve upon just storing those objects in Git.